# please delete my account

Tags: support, user-accounts, duplicate-accounts

I am using ask ubuntu from another account and as I was confused how stackexchange openid and all things work, I messed up. So please delete this account or tell me if there's another way out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the contact support page (https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and select *I need to delete my user profile* from the dropdown box. Follow the instructions.

Comment: OP is not really leaving; he has two accounts (is what I understand).